# Reading many files in parallel

Tags: c++, boost, io, signal-processing

I have a cross platform project in C++ where I am mixing audio in real-time. I have several independent tracks as input, that I read from separate files on disk. I then mix these, apply some processing, and spit out a buffer with the resulting audio. The problem I am having is that of disk IO speed. For the current test I am performing, I have about 10 tracks that are read simultaneously from disk. Each track is in raw PCM, 48000 HZ 16 bit stereo. This means that there is a significant amount of data that needs to be read as quickly as possible. I have tried both simple fread calls as well as memory mapped files through Boost, but the issue is the same. When a file is first opened, it usually causes the audio to break up (presumably while the file is read into cache by the OS). After that, everything runs smoothly without a glitch. For the time being I use one thread per file in the common case, sometimes two files per thread. It is usually when I have two files per thread that the stalling/breakup of the stream occurs. Note that I do not know in advance which input files that need to be played, as this is controlled by the user. So my problem is how to read these initial blocks in such a way so that I don't get stalling/breakup. Also, when a new file is loaded it is not necessarily in the beginning that the reading must start.

I have a few thoughts:

1. Can we prefetch the files into cache by reading all of them once at startup but disregarding the data? I cannot store all of it in memory. But it seems bad to rely on internal behavior of the OS's read cashe, especially since this is cross platform.
2. Can we use a format such as Ogg Vorbis for compression, load the compressed data fully into memory and then decode on the fly? I am thinking that decoding 10 or more Vorbis streams might be too CPU intensive, but I have no benchmarks yet. At least in this way we turn it from an I/O bound task to a CPU bound one.
3. Can we do any other kind of clever buffering approach to make it so that the large reads are more equally distributed? I know very little about how I might accomplish that.

I am stuck at this point, and would appreciate any suggestions that might improve throughput.

Comment: What OS & processor are we talking about? 10 x 48K x 16 x 2 = 15Mb/s or 2MB/s, which is WAY less than what my Linux machine can achieve (around 50-60MB/s).

Comment: I am testing on a Windows XP SP3 machine with 4 gb ram, and a 2.83 GHZ quad core processor. But my requirements are that it be cross platform. The stalling that occurs is only a few milliseconds, and only when a new file gets loaded. For the rest of the time it works flawlessly.

Comment: So, basically, it's the time it takes to open the file and read the first few bytes. In which case, "preloading" the first few kilobytes of the file before you start processing the data would be a suitable solution. I think any of the other options are just more work, with little or no benefit.

Comment: The trouble there is, as I mentioned in the question, that when a new file is opened it is not at all a guarantee that the first bytes that are needed are the first in the file. Since all tracks need to be kept in sync, I have to seek to the location where the mixer cursor is and begin reading the new file from there. So most of the time, in fact, we're starting at arbitrary locations in the file.

Comment: Do not read from all files simultaneously, this will make the hdd to move the heads, searching for in file location(next block). Try to read the files one after another(maybe on a maximum of 4 threads but also try in one thread)... and benchmark read operation, to observe which is the best...

Comment: When you say read files one after the other in 4 threads, wouldn't that still create parallel reading - just a little less of it?

Comment: The first step is to figure out a way that you can pre-load the data you need - when I said "first bytes", I mean first bytes you're going to use, not (necessarily) the first bytes of the file. I expect that you do know what your code is going to do, so you can let it run through a loop of "prefetch data" before you start the actualy mixing, right?

Comment: yes, it will, that's why i have updated the comment, to test on only one thread to see how it goes...

Comment: @mats: I do not know in advance what tracks the user will switch to, and at what time. I have no way of knowing that in advance, or I could easily prefetch as you suggest. But users switch tracks in real-time, in an unspecified manner.

Comment: Then you're stuffed... Unless you ALWAYS read all the files all the time, just use a "times zero" volume...

Comment: That would be problematic, as there can be several versions of each track so that 50 or more files is not uncommon even if we only have 10 tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the file loading using event processing.

This is where you open a bunch of file descriptors and let the operating system notify your programs when data is available.

The most broadly available api to do this with "select" (http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), wbut there are better methods ( poll, epoll, kqueue ). These are not available everywhere.

There are libraries that abstract this for you ( libev and libevent ).

So the way you do it is, one thread opens all the files you need and sets a 'watcher' on them. When data is available the watcher triggers, and call a callback.

The advantage is that you don't have a ton of threads waiting and sleeping checking all your open file descriptors. If that doesn't work then likely you are over saturating the hardware's io bandwidth - in which case you just have to wait. If that is the case then you need to do some buffering to avoid stutters.

Comment: If the input comes from a user callback, so that I don't actually handle the reading of the file itself from my library, is there a way in which I can still use the event driven approach effectively? I basically need to invoke the user callback to retrieve the input samples for each file, but it's not necessarily a file in the end user's code. I want to invoke the callback in such a way so that it is still possible for the end user to perform this type of efficient I/O. Have you any advice?

Comment: You're writing a library that allows user written plugins? You're pretty much at their mercy how they write their IO code. You could provide your own plugin for getting data from files. Or you could create an API that lets them pass data back you either from a FILE* or from a callback. The callback API would be for plugins from hardware, or from a plugin sound lib, and the FILE api would be for file oriented plugins.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you need to perform file IO operations in a separate thread for real time operations. When user wants to mix a second audio file, you can just open a new thread and read the first N bytes of this second audio file and return the data read into the main thread. This will also cause a lag but it will not break the  audio flow.

Comment: I have to wait for the data to be read before I can mix the next audio frame, so wouldn't I still get breakup in the audio while I wait for the reading operation to finish in the other thread?

Comment: @user749473 You can mix the audio files with a lag, as soon as you get some pre defined number of bytes, you can add them to the current buffer. Is synchronization so important? I mean, as soon as user pushes the button do you need to start mixing?

Comment: Oh I have a mix-ahead buffer, but the more I increase it the less of an immediate reaction the user gets when they make a change. Right now, I set the mix-ahead to 200 milliseconds. I wonder whether it is a good idea to set it any higher.

Comment: Do you read a second file in the same thread which plays audio?

Comment: No, but I push data to a queue which is then read from by the audio playback thread. If the queue starves, the audio stalls. So the starvation occurs no matter where I read the actual file data.